# Flutter show container on other container

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show container on top right of other container but its showing inside of it.

My code

```
      Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xffd1e6f5),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icon/notification.svg",
                ),
          ),
        ),
        new Positioned(  // draw a red marble
          top: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xff009fe1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Text('01'),
          ),),
        )
      ]
    )
```

[image]

I want to show it outside a light container like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need an external container to simulate the overlap effect.
Check the behavior of that component and try replicate your desired behavior.

```
 Container(
          height: 140.0,
          width: 140.0,
          color: Colors.amber, // set as transparent.
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                   ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Container(
                    width: 40.0, height: 40.0, 
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                   )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Marcos. I would like to tell you about this package [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

**Example Usage**

```
Badge(
  badgeContent: Text('3'),
  child: Icon(Icons.settings),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
 Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 50.0,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 17,
            right: 17,
            child: Container(
              width: 25.0,
              height: 25.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue[200],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(40),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                '01',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen -> [image]

You can also use Badge package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

```
 Badge(
            badgeColor: Colors.blue,
            animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
            toAnimate: true,
            position: BadgePosition.topEnd(
              top: -10,
              end: -10,
            ),
            badgeContent: Text(
              '01',
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 50.0,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffd1e6f5),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen using package -> [image]